# c# get the matched value from an string array of a string

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

i have a long string that I want to see if it  matches anything from a string array

```
string line = "this is a banana testing quote.";
string[] searchList = new string[4] {"b", "quote", "tee", "obb"};
```

I will first need to find if the line contains any string from the `searchList`.

```
if(searchList.Any(line.Contains))
```

and it can check if there is any match from the searchList, in this case, it should be "quote". but the checking can only check if it contains without knowing which exact string from the string array is matched.

Is there any better way to get the matched value, eg: `string matchedValue = "serachList[2]` or `string matchedValue = "quote"` other than looping the whole string for checking again?

I cannot loop through the string array `searchList` one by one as I am reading a big log, I think it is faster and better to use.Any()

Comment: I don't think you can avoid looping. Even if you could come up with something like a Linq expression for this - underneath, it would have to loop so it can test each item in `searchList` again `line`

Comment: You could string.split your line variable and join line and searchList, the result would be your containing words.